# Make action from Observable RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Stack a little bit in a simple situation. So, i have some upload action on page looks like:

```
onUpload$: Subject<SomeUpload> = new Subject<SomeUpload>();
uploadAction$: Observable<Action> = this.onUpload$.map(entity => this.someActionService.upload(entity));
```

This uploadAction$ use subscribe in agnular2 component, based on state

```
this.subscription = Observable.merge(
  this.uploadAction$
).subscribe(this.store);
```

action send to server base64 image and in response i get url, this url i can get then like

```
someResponseUrl$: Observable<String> = this.store.let(getSomeUrlFromState());
```

so, i need to make something like callback, becose this url didn't used in templates, i'm just need manipulate data in code. Can someone help and explain, how to make action from this observable string, to get data and make callback with it. Thanks in advice!

P.S. i'm try something like this

```
uploadAction$: Observable<Action> = this.onUpload$.map(entity => 
  this.someActionService.upload(entity))
    .do(() => {
      const subscription = 
        this.store.let(getSomeUrlFromState()).subscribe(url => {
        console.log(url)
      });
    });
```

its working, but i think it's weird way as solution...

Answer (score 0):

You could do for example the following but it depends on what you want to achieve and what you want to receive in the subscribers to `this.someActionService`:

```
uploadAction$: Observable<Action> = this.onUpload$
  .map(entity => this.someActionService.upload(entity))
  .mergeMap(() => this.store.let(getSomeUrlFromState()))
  .do(url => console.log(url));
```

You might want to use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: din't help :( in log i get `null` as url, and then angular 2 raise exception `Cannot read property 'type' of null`. Try use both operators, `mergeMap` and `concatMap`

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demo?